# How to define the period in a time series?

Tags: r

I am working with time series of agricultural production, the structure of my data is as follows

```
     Ja Fe Mar Apr May Jul Jun Ag Sep Oct Nov Dec
```

(year 1)  1  2  3   -   -   -   7   8  9   10   11 12

(year 2)  1  2  3   -   -   -   7   8  9   10   11 12

(year 3)  1  2  3   -   -   -   7   8  9   10   11 12

(year 4)  1  2  3   -   -   -   7   8  9   10   11 12

(year 5)  1  2  3   -   -   -   7   8  9   10   11 12

Where ( - ) are data in which there was no production, i.e. in April, May and June, because the period following the harvest (starting in July and ending in March of the other year), according to the agricultural cycle, there was no harvest, so imputing these months is not an option. Since I want to make predictions, I have tried the following:

```
     J F M J A S  O  N  D
```

(year 1) 1 2 3 7 8 9 10 11 12

(year 2) 1 2 3 7 8 9 10 11 12

(year 4) 1 2 3 7 8 9 10 11 12

(year 5) 1 2 3 7 8 9 10 11 12

I eliminated the months that had no production.

Before my syntax to define the series was:
**ST = ts( crop , start=c(1990,1), freq=12)**

From 1990 to 2013, but now I have no idea how to define the new series without spending years.

Any contribution is welcome, thank you in advance.

Comment: This seems to be a general statistics question rather than specific to programming in R

Comment: Thanks Miff for commenting :) , you're right I rambled a lot, but I've already worded the question better.

Answer (score 0):

***I found the answer to my question.***
1st I define the (-) as NA
then the syntax would be:
**ts(na.omit(crop),start=c(1990,1),freq=9)**